# How can i get pair of the json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object

```
data = 
   {"user" : [
    {
        "id"   : 1,
        "name" : "jeboo",
        "level": 1          
    },
    {
        "id"   : 2,
        "name" : "yoyo",
        "level": 1
    },
    {
        "id"   : 3,
        "name" : "yaya",
        "level": 2          
    },
    {
        "id"   : 4,
        "name" : "yeye",
        "level": 2
    },
    {
        "id"   : 5,
        "name" : "yiyi",
        "level": 3      
    },
    {
        "id"   : 6,
        "name" : "jebee",
        "level": 3          
    }
]}
```

this is how i get json object

```
var obj = JSON.stringify(data);
var parse = JSON.parse(obj);                
$.each(parse, function(key, object) {                                    
  $.each(object, function(index, val) {
     console.log(index, val);                        
  });                    
});
```

my purpose is want to produce the array below

object 0 + object 1 = first pair

object 2 + object 3 = second pair

object 4 + object 5 = third pair

Comment: do you want the pairs to be in array?

Comment: for(var i=0;i<parse.length-1;i+=2){

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Jefree Sujit, yes


Jonasw, ur answer was not solved my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want objects with same `level` in pairs,
You can use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to achieve this:

```js
var data = 
   {"user" : [
    {
        "id"   : 1,
        "name" : "jeboo",
        "level": 1          
    },
    {
        "id"   : 2,
        "name" : "yoyo",
        "level": 1
    },
    {
        "id"   : 3,
        "name" : "yaya",
        "level": 2          
    },
    {
        "id"   : 4,
        "name" : "yeye",
        "level": 2
    },
    {
        "id"   : 5,
        "name" : "yiyi",
        "level": 3      
    },
    {
        "id"   : 6,
        "name" : "jebee",
        "level": 3          
    }
]};

var r = data.user.reduce(function(res, obj) {
  res[obj.level - 1] = res[obj.level - 1] || [];
  res[obj.level - 1].push(obj);
  return res;
}, []);

console.log(r);
```

**EDIT**

If you want to pair the objects according to their position in the array and independent of `level` property then you can use callback's `index` argument and a bit of math:

```
var r = data.user.reduce(function(res, obj, idx) {
  res[Math.floor(idx/2)] = res[Math.floor(idx/2)] || [];
  res[Math.floor(idx/2)].push(obj);
  return res;
}, []);
```

Comment: thanks you for great answer. can u please help me to mark my question to be positive :)

Comment: but i am not depend on the level property, i want to pair the object array